# Solving Logarithm, Can't Use Quadratic Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have a logarithmic equation that I am meant to find the value of $x$ for:

$2\log_{9}(x)$ = $1/2$ + $2\log_{9}(5x+18)$

I get as far as here when I realize I cannot use the quadratic formula.

$\log_{9}\left( \dfrac{x^{2}}{(5x+18)^2}\right)= \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: But you know what to do with $\log_9(x^2)=\log_9(3)+\log_9((5x+18)^2)$, yes?

Answer (score 1):

From (note, I corrected a slight error)
$$
\log_9\Bigl( ({x\over 5x+18})^2\Bigr)={1\over2}.
$$
Get rid of the logarithm, by writing
$$
  ({x\over 5x+18})^2 =9^{1/2},
$$
and proceed from there.

Comment: I should point out that what I used in the above was $\log_a x=y\iff x=a^y$.

Answer (score 0):

No need to introduce squares. Simplify the original equation to
$$
\log_9({x\over 5x+18})={1\over4}
$$
and then to
$$
{x\over 5x+18}=9^{1\over4}.
$$